# Why does C output these carats?

Tags: c

I'm writing a hex-to-base64 encoder as an exercise, since I'm new to C. Nevermind why the code isn't working the way I want it to, why am I getting these carat-letter combos next to my output?

```
const char * hex_to_base64(const char * s) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < strlen(s)/3; i = i + 3) {
    char str[3];
    str[0] = s[i];
    str[1] = s[i+1];
    str[2] = s[i+2];
    printf("%s\n", str);
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  const char * x = "4453def6d206b696c6c696e6720796f757220627261696e206c696b652061222226f789436f6e6f5573206dabb7368726fa4b2";
  hex_to_base64(x);
  return 0;
}
```

And I'm getting this output:

```
445
3de^C
f6d^F
206 
b69^L
6c6^O
c69^R
6e6^U
720^X
796^[
f75^^
722!
```

Could someone explain why I am getting the carat-letter combos at the end of printf?

Comment: Those must be the hex codes for control characters.

Comment: I think your loop is flawed in any case.  If `s` is 30 characters long, `i` goes from `0` to `3` to `6` to `9` to `12`, and the loop ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're passing a non-zero-terminated string to printf(). Change:

```
char str[3];
```

to

```
char str[4];
str[3] = '\0';
```

Even better, move the declaration and zero-assignment outside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
char str[3];
str[0] = s[i];
str[1] = s[i+1];
str[2] = s[i+2];
printf("%s\n", str);
```

`str` should be null-terminated. You have to change `str` declaration to:

```
char str[4] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

Other people have already pointed out the bugs in your program, but your question was "why I am getting the carat-letter combos", and the answer to that is that the caret-letter combinations are your terminal's representation of various non-printing characters that you are attempting to print (due to the aforementioned bugs).

Comment: I don't think that's true. Program output that is fed to a terminal is not post-processes in this way. That applies only to echo of user input if the terminal is in cooked mode. I think that the memory location following `str[2]` on the OP's system must have contained an actual `^` character.

Comment: That's a remarkably consistently-placed `^` symbol for random memory, then. Another way for non-printing characters to be represented in that manner is if the output was redirected to a file, and the file is being viewed using vi.

Comment: Well, it's the same call stack each time, which means it's the same memory location each time, so plausibly the same contents too. But good point about the output being redirected.